# Reopen review queue is untypically high

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I saw that the length of the review queue for reopen votes is <20 but when I wake up today and check [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) it is >640.

[image]

Is there something wrong with it?

I have never seen this high a queue for reopen votes. Is there some bug in it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These were added to the queue by Shog. This was discussed in the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4763234#4763234):

> there you go, 600 reopen tasks to play with.

Comment: This is live site not a platform to play. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126192/shape-recognition-algorithms) eligible for reopen as per policy? No edit at all

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName then, what are those delete votes for?

Comment: I have check(notice) that many low quality post with high upvote are there in reopen queue. That should be reopen?

Comment: @ketan Review the questions based on what you think of them, not their score (which represents what others thought of them, years ago).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yeah exactly what i am saying. Still some people put them on reopen queue.

Comment: @ketan Shog9 (an SE employee) added them based on some heuristic -- probably "old, highly-voted, not recently reopen-reviewed" (I'm guessing here).  When I did my reviews, I left 29 closed... but edited one, which was reopened.  The point is not that they "should" be reopened -- many shouldn't.  It's to salvage what can be salvaged, and to surface the really bad ones to delete voters.

Comment: It's an experiment. The more important question is how to interpret the results. For example: What percentage of once closed highly scored questions gets deleted/downvoted/upvoted/reopened/left closed when reviewed again? If the result is not overwhelmingly for left closed one could feed more old closed questions into this queue which is usually quite empty. If however most of them are just left closed, no need for re-revieweing them. - Just my theory about why Shog9 did it...

Comment: I went through 30 reopen votes today and only 1 was even remotely worth reopening. The rest were old closed tool reqs / far too broad.

Comment: As if there wasn't enough crap on the site already...

Comment: Just finished the review queue. Only 2 reopen votes. If the results of this experiment are investigated please split by close reason. Because that 15 old, closed questions about recommendations are not even worth looking at. They are simply still off-topic. What a waste of time.

Comment: I did my reopen review too and it wasn't completely wasted, I found lots of things to delete vote on. I'd recommend leaving these reviews to those with delete vote previligies. Oh and then there was a few actual re-open cases of recent posts, that wasn't caused by Shog's experiment.

Comment: The question is, why attention for deleting old questions handled via the Reopen queue? I for instance can't even vote to delete, so going through these is an exercise in futility for me.

Comment: @Magisch Maybe deleting old questions is just a side effect, they could also be reopened instead. For all I care they could automatically delete all closed recommendation questions. Anyway, what would be a sensible rule to fill a potential delete vote queue that is then only shown to those who can do it?

Comment: @Trilarion Something like closed for X amount of time or Closed and below Y score.